# Partially color a cell value in vsto C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to color particular text inside the cell. Am able to color the whole value.

Let say my header of a column looks like Type(Irreversible) . I need to color only Irreversible in Red.

How to do this VSTO C#?

Comment: Can you give us some code example or what you've tried?

Comment: Look at the `Characters` collection

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks it worked